Helius Listener for NFT_SALE on NFT Collections
I want to conduct studies on different NFT collections that are being sold on various marketplaces using helius listeners. For example if I wanted to get notified every time a SMB was sold on a marketplace. What are some good practices or methods of how I should go about this?
I tried listening to the contract address: SMBtHCCC6RYRutFEPb4gZqeBLUZbMNhRKaMKZZLHi7W?
https://explorer.solana.com/address/SMBtHCCC6RYRutFEPb4gZqeBLUZbMNhRKaMKZZLHi7W
but nothing showed up and when checked on https://solscan.io/token/GMoemLuVAksjvGph8dmujuqijWsodt7nJsvwoMph3uzj#transactions I saw transactions that went through but nothing came up on my helius log.
I can get this working with fungible tokens no prob, but kinda stuck on how to handle this with NFTs.
Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Helius might have some other tooling available to do this, but something to realize is that each NFT has a different mint address. If you want to see transactions for all NFTs in a collection, you'll need to subscribe to all the mints included, so that would be SMBtHCCC6RYRutFEPb4gZqeBLUZbMNhRKaMKZZLHi7W, GMoemLuVAksjvGph8dmujuqijWsodt7nJsvwoMph3uzj, and everything else
